# Whats the best way to override object deletion in Sonata Admin?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I already have a custom CRUD controller. So do I just need to override `Controller::deleteAction()` and `Controller::batchDeleteAction()` from `Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller` ?

Or is it preferable / better practice to override the Admin class's delete methods?

My desired behaviour is that I want to update a record with an archived flag rather than delete the entity.

The docs are [incomplete](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_delete.html) on this subject

**Update**

The following code in my Entity's Repository class iterates over a query object as per the `batchDelete` method in the `ModelManager`

```
public function batchArchive($class, ProxyQuery $queryProxy)
    {

        $queryProxy->select('DISTINCT '.$queryProxy->getRootAlias());

        try {
            $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();

            $batchSize = 20;
            $i = 0;

            foreach ($queryProxy->getQuery()->iterate() as $pos => $object) {

                $this->archiveMyEntity($object); //???
                if (($i % $batchSize)  == 0) {
                    $entityManager->flush();
                    $entityManager->clear();
                }
                ++$i;
            }

        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            throw new ModelManagerException('', 0, $e);
        } catch (DBALException $e) {
            throw new ModelManagerException('', 0, $e);
        }
    }
```

The problem I have is that the object my archiveMyEntity() method expects is an Entity object not a query object.

Comment: The totally fucked up documentation of SonataAdminBundle is still empty even 4 YEARS later :/ How crazy

Answer (score 5):

I overwrote the delete logic in the admin class than in my custom CRUD controller I overwrote the batchActionDelete logic with the following:

```
public function batchActionDelete(\Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ProxyQueryInterface $query)
    {
        if (false === $this->admin->isGranted('DELETE')) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }

        $res = $query->execute();

        if (count($res)) {
            foreach ($res as $sqTeamEntity) {
                $this->admin->delete($sqTeamEntity, false);
            }

            $this->admin->flushDoctrine(); //custom method in the admin class
            $this->addFlash('sonata_flash_success', 'flash_batch_delete_success');
        }

        return new RedirectResponse(
            $this->admin->generateUrl('list',
                $this->admin->getFilterParameters())
        );
    }
```

So I fetch all the entities and just call the delete method from the admin class.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to override the controller logic or view, overriding the methods you indicated is the way to go.

However, if your objective is to perform custom logic before or after the deletion, you may override the `Admin::preRemove($object)` or `Admin::postRemove($object)` methods.

You may as well override the whole logic by overriding the `Admin::delete($object)` method.

Feel free to submit a PR - or comment in the related Github issue - to improve the docs as well.

Comment: This will not work! delete() in AbstractAdmin shows that whatever you do in the preRemove methods, it will not stop delete() from deleting the object.